# atom editor (snap) opens with two strange tabs

Tags: 20.04, snap, atom

I have a project with several files that are opened automatically when I launch the `atom` editor.

Recently, the `atom` editor (version 1.48) starts with two empty files with strange names:

```
ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false
```

and

```
atom
```

It tries to save the first file in my home directory and the second file to the `/usr/bin` directory (which is not possible due to permissions, of course).

So, I reverted to `atom` version 1.47 (snap revision 252) where this problem does ***not*** occur.

Is there something wrong with revision 257 of `atom` snap?

---

**Update:** Same problem with version 1.49.0 too!

---

**Update:** Same problem with version 1.50.0 too!

Comment: This issue needs to be reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I able to get solve this without re-installing /changing installation source by doing the following:

- Close tabs without saving (delete the files if you had previously saved them)
- Exit/Close Atom completely
- Open a terminal and navigate to `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`
- `sudo` open with your preferred text editor: `sudo nano atom_atom.desktop`
- Truncate the 'Exec' line to `Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/atom_atom.desktop /snap/bin/atom`
  (i.e., remove the last parameters that open those files)
- Save the file (overwriting the existing) and restart Atom; the tabs should no longer appear

Comment: Thank you! That was starting to nerve me. Thank you :)